# Google Analytics - Stacked Column Chart - How to add more X-axis tick marks

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-visualization

I have a page in a web app showing new users vs. users, and I'm charting it in a column chart. The JS looks like this:

```
var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
        metrics: 'ga:newUsers, ga:users',
        dimensions: 'ga:date',
        'start-date': beginDate,
        'end-date': endDate
    },
    chart: {
        container: 'chart1-container',
        type: 'COLUMN',
        options: {
            width: '100%',
            isStacked: true
        }
    }
});
```

The result stacked column chart looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see there no X-axis tick marks, and I would like to add them for each date in the chart. How would I do this?

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue? you can modify the chart on success...

Comment: In your answer to me, you included this option: hAxis: { ticks: chartTicks }, what does this do?

Comment: the `ticks` option takes an array and adds a tick mark / label for each value in the array for either the `hAxis` or `vAxis`. In the answer, I build an array with each date value in your data and add as `ticks` to the hAxis. If your data has multiple rows with the same date, you will need to remove the duplicates, the chart will actually list duplicate tick marks. see the [configuration-options](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the chart and redraw.
Not sure what your data looks like. But you may need to remove duplicates from `chartTicks`...

```
dataChart1.on('success', function(response) {
  // response.chart : the Google Chart instance.
  // response.data : the Google Chart data object.
  var chartTicks = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < response.data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    chartTicks.push(response.data.getValue(i, 0));
  }

  var options = {
    width: '100%',
    isStacked: true,
    hAxis: { ticks: chartTicks }  
  }

  response.chart.draw(response.data, options);
});
```